# Relationship problem and 'Illegal Filter on Attachment'

Tags: soql, attachment, error, relationships

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE Parent.Type = 'Contact'
```

When testing with an account, I get an error saying:

```
[MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY' exceptionMessage='Illegal filter on Attachment' ] row='-1' column='-1'
```

After a bit of googling, the only thing which (I think) comes close to an answer, is that SOQL polymorphism isn't enabled. Is that possible? If yes, how can I check that option, if no, what is the reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Haris

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the key prefix of the id. The first 3 chars of each id correspond to an Object type.

You could make your query like this:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
System.debug(keyPrefix);
keyPrefix += '%';

SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId LIKE = :keyPrefix
```

Comment: There's one problem with that: you can't use `LIKE` on IDs, since they're not Strings in the query; they have a distinct type.

Comment: Make a String type calc that equals ParentId

Answer (score 0):

SOQL Polymorphism is not currently available in Production environments, and as far as I know there is no definite date when it will be GA.

Try this:

```
Select ParentId from Attachment WHERE ParentId in (Select Id from Contact)
```

Now, this query as-is is not selective enough, but since your original one wasn't either, I assume you have some more criteria to add to a contact WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah, Contact was only an example. The query works on some prod. environments, so I guess it has to be manually enabled on this one particular.